# Deny creation of child node, if the node key is not the same as user id. Firebase Rules

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Suppose I have a database structure as follows:

```
/
    favorites
        ownerid_1
            favorite1_id
                title
                link
            favorite2_id
                title
                link
        ownerid_2
            etc
```

I can easily put Firebase permissions around these as follows:

```
{
    "rules": {
        "favorites": {
            "$owner_id": {
                ".read": "root.child('favorites').child($owner_id) == auth.uid",
                ".write": "root.child('favorites').child($owner_id) == auth.uid",
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However favorites are optional and the user can decide when to create their first favorite. The user's "$user_id" data structure does not exist until they do.

I'm struggling to work out how I can put in a validation rule at /favorites that will allow a new child node to be created by the user only when the key is the same as their user id.

i.e. ownerid_1 cannot create an ownerid_2 node.

I've tried the following but the simulator fails without specifying a specific line:

```
{
    "rules": {
        "favorites": {
            ".validate": "newData.hasChild(auth.uid)",

            "$owner_id": {
                ".read": "root.child('favorites').child($owner_id) == auth.uid",
                ".write": "root.child('favorites').child($owner_id) == auth.uid",
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Update #1**
Here's the logs without specifying any line in the Rules:

```
Type    write
Location    /favorites/
Data    { "JhDa8owfAkTRR5qMbuvAgEyUHYL2": { "favid1": { "title": "google", "link": "www.google.com" } } }
Auth    { "provider": "google", "uid": "JhDa8owfAkTRR5qMbuvAgEyUHYL2" }
Admin   false
```

**Update #2**

I have tried the following:

```
{
    "rules": {
        "favorites": {
            ".write": "newData.hasChild(auth.uid)",
            // This too: ".write": "newData.hasChildren([auth.uid])",
            "$owner_id": {
                ".read": "root.child('favorites').child($owner_id) == auth.uid",
                ".write": "root.child('favorites').child($owner_id) == auth.uid",
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which works, except it also allows the following to be successfully written:

```
"favorites": {
    "bad_data": "oops",
    "$owner_id": {
        "favoriteid_1": {
            "title": "google.com",
            "link": "www.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

It feels like we need an option like "onlyChildren" so that use cases of arbitrary data being written can be prevented.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my approach and it seems to have done the job. This basically says, you can write here as long as you're authenticated and you're not writing null... but if you do, then within the $owner_id tree...

1. The $owner_id must match your auth.uid, ensuring you only write to your location.
2. Both a 'title' and 'link' child is required, ensuring you do not write arbitrary data within /favorites.
3. The data type must be correct, ensuring good house keeping.

Here's the validation rules:

```
{
    "rules": {
        "favorites": {
            ".write": "auth.uid != null && newData.val() != null",
            "$owner_id": {
                ".read": "$owner_id == auth.uid",
                ".validate": "$owner_id == auth.uid && 
                              newData.hasChildren(['title', 'link']) &&
                              newData.child('title').isString() && 
                              newData.child('link').isString()"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Update**
Added check for null value.

Comment: IIRC, the cascading `.write` rule will allow any authenticated user to delete any user's favorites. The `.validate` rule will not prevent that.

Comment: I will test but could then add validation that newData != null

Comment: IIRC, `.validate` rules are simply not used for deletions. Only a `.write` rule will have an affect.

Comment: Could put it in the write rule.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be in you trying to get the child of a node that does not exist when you do:

> "root.child('favorites').child($owner_id) == auth.uid"

Change your rules to:

```
{
   "rules": {
       "favorites": {
           ".validate": "newData.hasChild(auth.uid)",
           "$owner_id": {
                ".read": "$owner_id === auth.uid",
                ".write": "$owner_id === auth.uid"
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure what you have suggested is functionally the same as what I already have and is scoped to the /favorites/ownerid_1 and below tree. I did try it and the outcome was the same though.

Comment: Added log to the original post.

Comment: You need to add a write permission on favorites as well to enable creation of the node. But you need to do it carefully, to make sure they dont write trash in there, or overwrite someone else&#39;s child. So make sure they are writing only one child and that the name of the child is equal to auth.id.

Comment: I've spent a few hours trying different combinations and it seems to come down this.. "make sure they are writing only one child and that the name of the child is equal to auth.id". I am completely stuck on how to ensure that they are only writing one child that matches their auth.uid. Something like this gets close.. ".write": "newData.hasChild(auth.uid)", but it doesn't stop someone correctly specifying a child node that matches their own uid, PLUS another data element that's arbitrary at the same level as their child node. Ideas?

Comment: I was trying to figure that out yesterday, but there's no method that counts the number of children in newData.

Comment: I'm starting to think that the only way would be to use a Firebase Cloud function...